# Changing names of columns in R

Tags: r

I would like to write a function for changing names of columns in dataframe. I have a lot of questionnaires(A, B, C..) and I would like to name columns for each questionnaire as sequences of questionnaire names and number expect of the first column which is named id (id, A1, A2, A3, id, B1, B2, B3, id, C1, C2, C3...).

I wrote a code like this:

```
col_names <- paste("A", 0:50, sep = "")
names(data) <- col_names
data <- rename(data, id = A0)
```

This works for specific questionniare A, which data si saved in dataframe named data, which length is 50, but I would like to turn this to the function that would rename columns of any dataframe..

Comment: Please consider using a [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) data format.  Your life will be much easier in the long run.  Here, a tidy format would have columns for `ResponderID`, `Questionnaire`, `Question` and `Response`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
my_rename = function(data, label = "A") {
  names(data) = c("id", paste0(label, 1:(ncol(data) - 1)))
}
```

It is dynamic based on the number of columns of data, and you can supply whatever `label` you would like, with a default of "A".

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of package `glue`:

```
library(glue)

column_names <- function(data, label = "A") {
  names(data) <- glue::glue("{label}{1:ncol(data)}")
  head(data)
}
```

Just bear in mind that when you enclose an expression like `label` or `1:ncol(data)` in braces {} they will be evaluated as R codes and the rest will be printed as character strings such is the case with `paste` function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple option for you using `setNames` and the builtin `airquality` dataset as example data:

```r
# Original variable names:

head(datasets::airquality)

#>   Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
#> 1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
#> 2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
#> 3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
#> 4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
#> 5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
#> 6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6

# New variable names:

mydataframe <- setNames(datasets::airquality, paste0('A', seq(1:length(datasets::airquality))))

head(mydataframe)

#>   A1  A2   A3 A4 A5 A6
#> 1 41 190  7.4 67  5  1
#> 2 36 118  8.0 72  5  2
#> 3 12 149 12.6 74  5  3
#> 4 18 313 11.5 62  5  4
#> 5 NA  NA 14.3 56  5  5
#> 6 28  NA 14.9 66  5  6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Or, if you wanted to see what it looks like in the `for loop`:

```r
column_rename_function <- function(x){
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    colnames(x)[i] <- paste0('A', i)
  }
  return(head(x))
}

column_rename_function(datasets::airquality)
#>   A1  A2   A3 A4 A5 A6
#> 1 41 190  7.4 67  5  1
#> 2 36 118  8.0 72  5  2
#> 3 12 149 12.6 74  5  3
#> 4 18 313 11.5 62  5  4
#> 5 NA  NA 14.3 56  5  5
#> 6 28  NA 14.9 66  5  6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>